# Tutorial of Raspberry Pi audio capabilities

Tags: audio

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspian installed.  When it comes to controlling the built-in audio architecture, I find many attempts on the internet that show how to accomplish some particular task.  I would like to find an overview of the built-in audio capabilities, and what commands control it.  Alsamixer looks very impressive, but when I use it, how do I know where the system thinks the mic input or audio input is, and how do I change those if I wish to use external input?  A good tutorial doesn't seem to exist on this topic.

Thanks in advance for any help.

jrdoner

Comment: There is no audio input on a Pi and AFAIK alsamixer doesn't think there is any either

Comment: When I brought up the browser to attempt to use Google meet, with a webcam plugged into USB, the google meet interface claimed I had a microphone.  Also, I find that the Audacity sound editor claims to run on Raspian, with the ability to record directly into the Pi.  So how is that possible if there is no audio input/

Comment: Rubbish software maybe? Fact is there is *no* audio input on a bare Pi...

Comment: Does your webcam have a builtin microphone?